# How do I toggle show/hide of hidden file in NetBeans 7.4?

Tags: netbeans, installation, hidden-files

Well, that is basically it:

How do I toggle show/hide of hidden file in NetBeans 7.4?

Every time I try to open a file in NetBeans 7.4 it shows all my hidden file and that is very annoying. I Googled it but could not find an answer until now.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to **Preferences** (macosx) > **Miscellaneous** > **Files**

In the textarea **Ignored Files Patterns** enter

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$
```

By removing the the `|^\.(?!(htaccess|gitignore)$).*$` from the default value you tell Netbeans not to remove any hidden files